# The method setColor(Color) is undefined for the type JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Error code shown below :

The method setColor(Color) is undefined for the type JFrame

```
package task3;

class Execute {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        
        Controller c = new Controller();    
        c.simulate();
        
    }
}

class Model {
    
    int l; //line
    int c; //column
    int[] loc = {0,0}; //location
    JFrame frame;
    int m_width;
    int m_height;
    int R = (int)(Math.random()*256);
    int G = (int)(Math.random()*256); 
    int B = (int)(Math.random()*256);
    
    public int getRectWidth() {
        return frame.getContentPane().getWidth() / c;
    }
    public int getRectHeight() {
        return frame.getContentPane().getHeight() / l;
    }
    
    
    Model(int width, int height, int line, int column, JFrame w) {
        m_width = width;
        m_height = height;
        l = line;
        c = column;
        frame = w;
    }
}
class View extends JComponent {
    
    private Model m_Mod;

    View(Model mod) {
        m_Mod = mod;
    }
    
    
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        
        super.paintComponent(g);
        for(int i=0; i<m_Mod.l; ++i) {
            for(int j=0; j<m_Mod.c; ++j) {
                g.fillRect(m_Mod.loc[0], m_Mod.loc[1], m_Mod.getRectWidth(), m_Mod.getRectHeight());
                m_Mod.loc[0] = m_Mod.loc[0] + m_Mod.getRectWidth() + 2;
            }
            m_Mod.loc[0] = 0;
            m_Mod.loc[1] = m_Mod.loc[1] + m_Mod.getRectHeight() + 2;
        }
        m_Mod.loc[1] = 0;
    }
}
class Controller extends JFrame{
    
    private Model m_Mod;
    private View m_View;
    
    
        Controller(){
                
                JFrame window = new JFrame();
                Color color = new Color(m_Mod.R, m_Mod.G, m_Mod.B);
                m_Mod.frame.setColor(color);
```

// Error code here : The method setColor(Color) is undefined for the type JFrame

```
                m_Mod = new Model(500,500,3,8, window);
                m_View = new View(m_Mod);
                window.add(m_View);
                window.setSize(m_Mod.m_width,m_Mod.m_height);
                window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                window.setVisible(true);
                window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                
        }
        void simulate(){
            //m_View.repaint();
        }
        
}
```

If I comment the Color section out the program works perfectly. Any ideas?
Furthermore the `setColor()` method is in the Java Frame class,no? So why is it not working?
Some sites tell me to update my library

Comment: setForeground(color)

Comment: Not working. The compiler allows it but the rectangles don't change the colors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Furthermore the setColor() method is in the Java Frame class,no?

Did you read the API? That is the first step you do when attempting to solve a problem.

You can't set the color of a JFrame. You can set the foreground/background of components added to the frame.

Typically you would use the `setBackground()` on the panel that you add to the frame:

```
m_View = new View(m_Mod);
m_View.setBackground(...); // added
window.add(m_View);
```

However this won't work because you are extending JComponent which doesn't paint the background by default.

If you want to extend JComponent then you need to add painting code:

```
super.paintComponent( g );

g.setColor( getBackground() );
g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

g.setColor( getForeground() ); // default color for your custom painting
```

Or, the easier approach is to just extend `JPanel` since a JPanel will automatically paint the background with the color you set.

Comment: I just need to put the `setColor() method` in the `paint method` Now it works. Your provided solution is not working for me.

Comment: Did you invoke the setForeground(...) method on your View component? This will make the color of all the objects you paint the same Color.

Comment: `setForeground()` is not needed here since I want to paint different colors. I solved my own problem which you can see in my answer below.

Comment: *I solved my own problem* - which is part of what I suggested in my answer above. Also, you still need to clear the background to make sure you don't have painting artifacts. Again, I mention this in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `setColor() method` needs to be called inside the `paintComponent method`. That was my mistake here. Now it works and the rectangles are drawed in color.